# Define post parameters using annotations - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, post, web, symfony-2.3

I have a controller on a project built on top of Symfony2 and I would like to know if there is a way to define the post method parameters using method annotations similarly to how you can do it for the get method parameters.

I'm not talking about URL parameters - I'm talking about naming the the payload parameters so they get automatically assigned to the method parameters.

```
/**
 * @Route("/path/{parameter}")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function myMethod($parameter){
}

/**
 * @Route("/path/")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Parameter("parameter") <--- Something like this.
 */
public function myMethod($parameter){
}
```

Is this feasible with the Sensio bundle or does it only support URL parameters?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The automatic injection of the *route placeholders* (not GET/POST parameters!) is done by the Symfony framework, it has nothing to do with the Symfony framework.

When the parameter name matches a route attribute name, it'll be injected. This doesn't work for neither POST nor GET parameters. However, you can create your own [Parameter Converter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) (feature of the SensioFrameworkExtraBundle) to make something like this yourself.

Comment: Hi, does this apply only to URL parameters or also to payload parameters?